# Character counting function giving an output for each successive character

Tags: python

So i have this code that is supposed to count the characters in a user inputted sentece

```
import pprint
message = str(input())
count = {}

for character in message:
    count.setdefault(character, 0)
    count[character] = count[character] + 1
    pprint.pprint(count)
```

however the problem is, it gives an output for every successive character i.e if you give a sentence with 3 characters in it e.g "the" it will give 3 outputs

```
the
{'t': 1}
{'h': 1, 't': 1}
{'e': 1, 'h': 1, 't': 1}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

how do i get it only to give the final output with all characters counted? thanks

Comment: What is the output format that you would like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your objective correctly; this might work. `if character.isalpha()` filters non alphabetic characters in the string like `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~` and white spaces only take into account the alphabetic letters.

```
from pprint import pprint
message = 'This is a test string to check whether character to occurences mapping works correctly' #str(input())
occurrences_dict = {}

for character in message:
    if character.isalpha() and character not in occurrences_dict:
        occurrences_dict[character] = message.count(character)
pprint(occurrences_dict)

{'T': 1,
 'a': 4,
 'c': 9,
 'e': 8,
 'g': 2,
 'h': 5,
 'i': 4,
 'k': 2,
 'l': 1,
 'm': 1,
 'n': 3,
 'o': 5,
 'p': 2,
 'r': 8,
 's': 6,
 't': 8,
 'u': 1,
 'w': 2,
 'y': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting multiple outputs because the print (`pprint.pprint`) is in a `for` loop.

Just remove the indentation from the `pprint.pprint(count)` line, so that it isn't in the `for` loop:

```
import pprint
message = str(input())
count = {}

for character in message:
    count.setdefault(character, 0)
    count[character] = count[character] + 1
pprint.pprint(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You print the output every line so this is expected. You can achieve the same with much simpler code using `Counter` -

```
from collections import Counter
import pprint

message = str(input())
count = Counter(message)
pprint.pprint(dict(count))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pprint
message = str(input())
count = {}

for character in message:
    count.setdefault(character, 0)
    count[character] = count[character] + 1
pprint.pprint(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

you just have to take off `pprint.pprint(count)` from `for` cycle

```
import pprint
message = str(input())
count = {}

for character in message:
    count.setdefault(character, 0)
    count[character] = count[character] + 1

pprint.pprint(count)
```

output:

```
messaggio
{'a': 1, 'e': 1, 'g': 2, 'i': 1, 'm': 1, 'o': 1, 's': 2}
```